# Which open source licenses allow distribution of binary executable/library without a copyright notice?

Tags: open-source, licensing

Let's say write a C library, and I want all versions of the source to carry my copyright/license, but I want users of the library distributing executable code, static or dynamically linked library to be a able to do so without restriction (including making reference to my particular license).  Does such an open source license exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the [zlib/libpng license](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/zlib-license.php) and the [Boost license](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/bsl1.0.html) fit those criteria.

Answer (score 0):

There is always the [DWTFYW](http://podwg.berlios.de/DWTFYW.txt) License :)